# tabs/menu dropdown position not working

Tags: html, css

I am sorry in advance I could not get this to work in jsfiddle. I really am just not sure how to do it and I've spent way too long trying to figure it out.

Anyway I have this zozo tab (which no longer offers support) I am using [HERE](http://www.hauppauge.com/responsive/pages/products/zozo-test.html), When I make the window small for mobile size and click the "Overview" link that entire drop down menu goes under so there seems to be two "Overviews" instead of on top of it. Can someone please help me figure this out? I would great appreciate it!

CSS her [HERE](http://www.hauppauge.com/responsive/plugins/zozo-tabs/css/zozo.tabs.css) and [HERE](http://www.hauppauge.com/responsive/plugins/zozo-tabs/css/zozo.tabs.flat.css)

JS for tabs is [HERE](http://www.hauppauge.com/responsive/plugins/zozo-tabs/js/zozo.tabs.min.js)

[image]

Comment: It looks like you have a duplicate entry in the list? How are you implementing this? Pure jQuery or are you using data elements?

Comment: Hi, I do not have a duplicate entry. There is JQuery but I'm sorry I'm not sure what you mean by data elements. It was a plug-in I purchased from Envato but since has no support anymore. I have invested so much time with this I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: I would simply use bootstrap, what you're attempting to do is rather easy with bootstrap 3. I do not really know about this plugin, sorry.